# How to show individual names in a column according to the value of other column? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, bubble-sort

I have this code where i am sorting out the shortest processing time first. I am using a CSV file as a input where i have data columns like "TestCaseName", "Average_processing_time". Using the Average_processing_time column i am sorting the shorting the shortest processing time first. Using bubble sort i got the results but i also want testcase name in a separate column parallel to the processing time.

Currently the testcase names are as per the CSV (alphabetical order). But instead i want the testcase name according to the average processing time.
Here is the code i have currently:-

```
          pt=[]     #pt stands for processing time

          n=int(df.TestCaseName.count())
          processes=[]
          for i in range(0,n):
                 processes.insert(i,i+1)

          pt=list(map(float, df["ProcessingTime"]))
          for i in range(0,len(pt)-1):  #applying bubble sort to sort process according to their processing time
             for j in range(0,len(pt)-i-1):
                   if(pt[j]>pt[j+1]):
                      temp=pt[j]
                      pt[j]=pt[j+1]
                      pt[j+1]=temp
                      temp=processes[j]
                      processes[j]=processes[j+1]
                      processes[j+1]=temp
             wt=[]    #wt stands for waiting time
             avgwt=0  #average of waiting time
             #tat=[]    #tat stands for turnaround time
             #avgtat=0   #average of total turnaround time
             wt.insert(0,0)
             #tat.insert(0,bt[0])
             for i in range(1,len(pt)):  
                  wt.insert(i,wt[i-1]+pt[i-1])
                  #tat.insert(i,wt[i]+bt[i])
                  avgwt+=wt[i]
                  #avgtat+=tat[i]
             avgwt=float(avgwt)/n
             #avgtat=float(avgtat)/n
             print("\n")
             print("Process\t\t Processing Time\t\t Waiting Time \t\t TestCaseName") #\t\t\t  
             Turn Around Time
             for i in range(0,n):
                  #  print('{} {} {} {}'.format(processes[i], df.TestCaseName[i], bt[i], 
                  wt[i])
                  #txt = "{0}, \t\t{1}, \t\t{2}, \t\t\t{3}".format(processes[i], bt[i], wt[i], 
                  df.TestCaseName[i] )
                  print(str(processes[i])+"\t\t"+str(pt[i])+"\t\t"+str(wt[i])+ 
                  "\t\t"+str(df.TestCaseName[i]))
                  #print(txt)
                  print("\n")
            print("Average Waiting time is: "+str(avgwt))
            #print("Average Turn Arount Time is: "+str(avgtat))
```

[CSV structure & Output i am getting currently Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4jju.png)

[Output i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6qaz.png)

Comment: Since you haven't provided any input data from which I could test, I can only surmise that the reason you aren't getting data organized the way you want is that you have sorted the process time but have not adjusted the df testcase names in sync.  If you provide a sample of the input data, I could test further

Comment: @itprorh66 I have provided a picture of CSV structure. If you want that CSV file then i dont know if i can upload a csv file in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

you can easily create the following dataframe using:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('Filename')
```

This yields the dataframe:

```
    TestCase_Name   Avg_Proc_Time
  0    A            2
  1    B            6
  2    C            1
  3    D            7
```

To sort this frame simply do:

```
df.sort_values(by='Avg_Proc_Time')
```

which produces the desired output

```
    TestCase_Name   Avg_Proc_Time
2      C                1
0      A                2
1      B                6
3      D                7
```

Comment: Yes i know this but i am actually implementing a algorithm here which is going to be used in real time. I can not use pandas for that. That is why i have this code which uses the concept of Shortest Job First.

Comment: It would have been nice if you had included this little tidbit of information in your original problem description.  I refer you back to my original comment, when doing the bubble sort, you need to tie the testcase name to the processing time, so that the sort moves both name and time as a pair.